# .htaccess redirect from subdomain's articles to main domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have subdomains: *sub1.tld.com*, *sub2.tld.com* and so on. This subdomains contain important info. But I want to prevent opening any other urls, for example: *sub1.tld.com/anypage* or *sub2.tld.com/dir/more/anyurl.html*. This urls must be redirected to main domain tld.com: *tld.com/anypage* or *tld.com/dir/more/anyurl.html*

So, i have to check 2 things before redirection:

1. it's any subdomain
2. it's not subdomain's root page

I created this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^.+\.tld\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)       http://tld.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This set of rules works as expected (redirects *sub1.tld.com/anypage* to *tld.com/anypage*) but also redirects *sub1.tld.com* to tld.com. Where is the error? 2nd string is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reason the most reliable for checking variable was %{THE_REQUEST}, not %{REQUEST_URI}.

%{THE_REQUEST} contains raw browser's query to web-server: for example, *GET /anypage.html HTTP/1.1*, if you are opening url http://anysite.com/anypage.html.

So, here you are complete working rule-set for .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^.+\.tld\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST}  ^get\ /(.+)\ http.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)           http://tld.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^.+\.tld\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$         http://tld.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you can use this string to check if it root:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\ HTTP/
```

Comment: No luck.. Redirect long and short urls :(